# How to use GetBufferSubData?

Tags: c#, opengl, unsafe, sharpgl

I am currently playing around with `SharpGL`  but can not figure out how to use it's function GetBufferSubData in proper way.

```
   public void GetBufferSubData(uint target, 
                                int offset, 
                                int size, 
                                IntPtr data);
```

Use case situation: I already fill VBO with some data and now want to get it from there back to managed object.

My attempts have failed with `FatalExecutionEngineError` which, as I read, corresponds to to leaks in memory heap. But I am not sure I have a proper code for my needs.

```
public virtual unsafe float[] GetFromBuffer(int offset, int length)
{
    float[] output = new float[length];

    Bind();

    fixed (float* array = output)
    {
        var ptr = new IntPtr(array);

        Gl.GetBufferSubData(Id, offset, sizeof(float) * length, ptr);

        // Not needed code (fixed after answer)
        //GCHandle handle = (GCHandle) ptr;
        //output = (handle.Target as float[]);
    }

    return output;
 }
```

My question is how to get data back to managed object.

Comment: `GetBufferSubData` is to get data from a bound VBO

Comment: @ratchet freak: is this makes any difference in my case?

Comment: you are talking about the VAO in your question which isn't used to store data, but store data bindings for rendering

Comment: @ratchet freak: thanks, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `GetBufferSubData()` is not the id (aka name) of the buffer, but the buffer target. You need to bind your buffer to the target first, and then use `GetBufferSubData` with the same target:

```
Gl.BindBuffer(OpenGL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Id);
Gl.GetBufferSubData(OpenGL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, sizeof(float) * length, ptr);
```